# Changed the textbox type in asp.net after run web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, textbox, passwords, controls

I am developing a web application. In that, there is textbox and the type is "password". Now when I run the application, the type is getting changed to "text". I have no idea on how this is getting changed.

```
<p class="input-row">
<asp:TextBox type="password" ID="txt1" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 120px"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="hint">Password</span>
</p>
```

after I run the web application this get changed to type="text".

```
  <p class="input-row">
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txt1" type="text" id="MainContent_txt1" style="padding-left: 120px">
        <span class="hint">Password</span>
        </p>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Type attribute on a TextBox you need TextMode

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the property `TextMode="Password"`

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx